# Unable to get text to rotate on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I've been trying to get this text to rotate once I click the div that it is in, but no matter what I try, it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <div class="list">
        <div class="listItem">Ash Gray<p>+</p></div>
        <div class="listItem"></div>
        <div class="listItem"></div>
        <div class="listItem"></div>
        <div class="listItem"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.listItem {
width: calc(100% - 60\5px);
height: 53px;
padding: 1px;
margin-left: 60px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color: #9265DC;
font-size:  1.5em;
text-align: left;
line-height: 55px;
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #9265DC;
border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.listItem p {
float: right;
line-height: 10px;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 10px;
font-weight: bolder;
}

.rotate {
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform-origin: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".listItem").click(function(){
  $(".listItem p").toggleClass("rotate");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/qRzrNq -- seems to work for me, did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to reference to the clicked element by `this` keyword instead, else if you click on one element, **all of the `p` elements** will be rotated.

Also added some transitions. Code snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".listItem").click(function() {
    $(this).find('p').toggleClass("rotate");
  });
});
```

```css
.listItem {
  width: calc(100% - 60\5px);
  height: 53px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #9265DC;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #9265DC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listItem p {
  float: right;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="listItem">Ash Gray
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="listItem">Misty
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="listItem">Brock
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="listItem"></div>
  <div class="listItem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added ? Your script depends on JQuery. I think you have, but you didn't put it above, so just had to point that out.

I'm getting the + to rotate by 45deg when clicking no sweat Remember though that you're only applying it to the first match JQuery gets, not all of them. Your function needs a bit of work so that you can handle each of them individually. Something like this:

```
<div class="listItem" onclick="rotate(this)">Ash Gray<p>+</p></div>
```

and  then

```
function rotate(dom) {
    dom.className += " rotate";
}
```